# A type that does NOT match a literal template

Tags: typescript, types

I want to make sure a string does not start with a $ with typescript types. Like in `x3` in the example:

```js
type DollarString = `$${string}`
type NoDollarString = string extends DollarString ? never : string;

const x1: DollarString = "$x";
const x2: DollarString = "x"; // As expected: Type '"x"' is not assignable to type '`$${string}`'
const x3: NoDollarString = "$x"; // Works but shouldn't
const x4: NoDollarString = "x"
```

However, assigning `$x` to `x3` does not lint an error.

Comment: There is no such type in TypeScript. TypeScript lacks both negated types and any sort of regexlike matching. Conditional types don't work that way, `string` doesn't split itself apart into an infinite union, so `NoDollarString` is just `string`. At best you can make a `CheckNoDollarString` *generic* type with a helper function like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdDOdN) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?